# Как посчитать количество байт для Y компоненты и UV компоненты в сжатом jpeg2000 изображении, чтобы добавить данные в заголовок ADV202?

Tags: c++, qt, jpeg

мне необходимо оформить ADV202 заголовок. Мне нужно расписать про 7 пакетов их длины в ADV заголовке и поделить их по формуле
для пакетов = (Размер компоненты Y + Размер компоненты UV) * 4

Как узнать где находятся в сжатых данных эти компоненты? Пересмотрел Маркеры у JPEG2000 но не вижу ничего указывающего на это.

Comment: Может это про subsampling имеется ввиду? Оно по идее где-то в заголовках должно фигурировать.

Comment: @user7860670 тоже так думал, но чет ничего такого не нашел(